# Rigify bones not inheriting parent rotation?

Tags: hair, rigify

I'm working on a hair rig for my character for a game I'm designing. I've done this by adding multiple strands of bones to a Rigify armature, both front and back hair models.

[image]

Each strand is given the tail rig type and is parented to spine.006.

[image]

The problem is that after the rig is generated, when I rotate either the head or the torso, the hair rig does not rotate along with the spine. How can I resolve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget CTRL + A Apply all transforms to reset the position and rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the bones rig type to *limbs.simple_tentacle*.

Comment: It's good that you found a solution but I don't think the rig type was the problem. Tail should also follow the parent...